# Redis OR check in MATCH

Tags: regex, redis, pattern-matching

As a beginner, I would like to know if there is a way to write below query in redis

```
Scan 0 MATCH Test:[keyword*:* | *:keyword]
```

Right now I have to do two separate scans for this query as below

```
Scan 0 MATCH Test:*:keyword*
Scan 0 MATCH Test:keyword*:*
```

Comment: You do not have a regex here, only some wildcard patterns, and if their syntax does not allow alternation, then there is no way to write it the way you showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you've 3 choices here:

1. Wrap both commands into a *Lua* script and call it as it would be a single command.
2. Instead of *scanning* do *indexing*. Create a *set* or *sorted set* where you'll store all elements that matches these patterns, and just perform a a *sscan* or *zscan* with no `MATCH`.
3. Keep doing it as you've done already.

Comment: Thanks. Will indexing, with lot of data keep changing continuous faster than what i am doing currently?

Comment: @Siddharth Probably yes, because you'll just do paging on a single set. For example, if you use a sorted set, you would be able to do paging without a `scan` at all.